# NSBlockOperation calling a method inside NSOperation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I have a question.
I have the following code:

```
NSBlockOperation *op=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        [[ClassA sharedInstance] someSingletonMethod:params1];
        [ClassB classBMethod:params2];
        [self currentClassMethod:params3];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kSNotificationName" object:nil];
        }];
    }];

[self.myOperationQueue addOperation:op];
```

Is it safe to call singleton methods in a block? Is it safe to call class methods in a block? Is it safe to call "self" methods?

I have a following situation. I'm sending a batch of requests to server:

```
AFHTTPClient *client=[[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:reqOps progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
    NSLog(@"finished: %i of %i requests", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
    [[PTDictionaryUpdate sharedInstance] debugPrint:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"finished: %i of %i requests", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations]];
} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"operations finished");
```

Here how I'm handling responses.
I'm creating operations to handle completed requests.

```
for (int i=0; i<[operations count]; i++)
    {
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation=[operations objectAtIndex:i];
        if ((operation.error==nil) && (operation.response.statusCode==200))
        {
            id JSON=operation.responseJSON;
            int handleMethodIndex=-1;
            for (int j=0; j<[urls count]; j++)
            {
                if ([operation.request.URL isEqual:[urls objectAtIndex:j]])
                {
                    handleMethodIndex=j;
                };
            };

            switch (handleMethodIndex) {
                case 0:
                {
                    //[self countryUpdate:JSON];

                    NSInvocationOperation *invOp=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(countryUpdate:) object:JSON];
                    [invOp setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityLow];
                    [handleJSONOperations addObject:invOp];
                    break;
                }
                case 1:
                {
                    //[self regionsUpdate:JSON];

                    NSInvocationOperation *invOp=[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(regionsUpdate:) object:JSON];
                    [invOp setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityLow];
                    [handleJSONOperations addObject:invOp];
                    break;
                }
                //.......
          //.......
       }
```

After I created an array with operations which will handle (process and update database) JSON that I pulled from the server:

```
NSBlockOperation *op=[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{

        //first we need to tether countries, regions and cities
        [[PTDataTetherer sharedInstance] tetherCountriesRegionsCitiesInContext:self.updateContext];

        //generating fake agencies
        //[PTFakeAgencyGenerator generateAgenciesInContext:context];

        //generating fake clients
        //[PTFakeClientGenerator generateClientsInContext:context];

        //generating fake reports
        [[PTFakeReportGenerator sharedInstance] generateReportsInContext:self.updateContext];

        //generating fake presentations
        [[PTFakePresentationGenerator sharedInstance] generatePresentationsInContext:self.updateContext];


        //tethering
        [[PTDataTetherer sharedInstance] tetherAgenciesWithOthersInContext:self.updateContext];
        [[PTDataTetherer sharedInstance] tetherClientsWithOthersInContext:self.updateContext];
        [[PTDataTetherer sharedInstance] tetherEventsWithOthersInContext:self.updateContext];
        [[PTDataTetherer sharedInstance] tetherPresentationFoldersWithImagesInContext:self.updateContext];

        [self saveContext];

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kSynchronizationFinishedNotification" object:nil];
        }];
    }];
    [op setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityLow];
    if ([handleJSONOperations count]==0)
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"kSynchronizationFinishedNotification" object:nil];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.serverUpdateQueue addOperation:updateContextCreateOperation];
        [handleJSONOperations addObject:op];
        [self.serverUpdateQueue addOperations:handleJSONOperations waitUntilFinished:NO];
    };
```

Basically I want to construct the queue in such way:
1. [context create operation]
2. [multiple context modify operations that will parse json received from server and save new/modify objects to/in context]
3. [some final methods that will also modify context and, at the end, that will call a save method to propagate changes to the storage and then using NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotifications to other context]

Comment: Why shouldn't it be safe? Have you experienced any problem (exception or crash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to call singletons methods in block?

It's a bit board question, depends on what you inside your singleton's method.

> Is it safe to call class methods in block?

Depends on what you do inside your method. From my experience and the code I do, yes.

> Is it save to call "self" methods?

You are passing a reference of `self` to the block, which might cause a memory leak.

Comment: Basically I want to do such thing:

Comment: @RuiAAPeres can you add more info about why memory leak *might* be or might not? Where is this edge. And another question, will this methods executes in that operation block or it will be in main thread (queue)?

Comment: @flinth depends if `self` holds a strong reference to the block and `self` is referenced inside the block. This is enough to have a retain cycle. The block operation depends on the queue where it's executed.